# How to pass computed data from Theme preprocess functions to Twig templates?

Tags: theming, nodes, 8

My general problem is this: I need to compute some data from PHP, usually using Drupal APIs, then pass computed values to a Twig template (in order to showing it).

For example: I have a template named `node--dog.html.twig` and inside this template I need to show the *total count* of *Dog*s I have inside the website. To do this I will compute from PHP the *total count*, using the `Drupal::entityQuery` API. But then I have to pass this computed value to the Twig template.

I tried to use a theme's *preprocess function* inside the file `<my_theme>.theme`:

```
function customtheme_preprocess_node__dog(&$variables) {
  //
}
```

From here I'm able to do all PHP computations, but I couldn't find any documentation explaining how to pass data to Twig views. Can I use the `$variables` object? Is there any drawbacks? Is there a better approach?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$variables` is an array, not an object.

But yes, it's the one and only way to pass additional data to the template. Anything you put in there is available in the template then. `$variables['hello'] = 'world';` can be printed with `{{ hello }}`.

Comment: Thank you @Berdir.. Inspecting the `$variables` array I saw that it already contains elements. Putting my data in it, is there no the risk to overwrite by mistake some element required internally by Drupal?

Comment: Well, of course there is if you don't check what's already in there. Use safe names, e.g. prefixed with your module or theme.

Comment: Ok. I will go with prefixed names.